# Angular Application Slowing Down On Chorme 121.0.6167.139

Tags: angular, google-chrome, css-animations, chromium

After a recent update on Chrome 121.0.6167.139, our Angular 7 app is slowed down on Chrome, Brave, and all Chromium-based browsers. On Firefox, it is working perfectly fine, and on the older version of Chrome it is working perfectly fine.

The slowdown is in terms of Animation. Animations are lagging; API calls are working fine with no issue from the backend.

To check what's causing this slowness, we checked the performance of the website. Here are some of the screenshots.

[image: Performance Of The website]

Browser is spending more time in Painting.

One more:

[image]

The Commit task is causing some issues: it is taking more time than usual.

We tried reducing animations on our website but no resolution.

Comment: Go to memory tab and do memory profiling to check where all the space gets allocate, maybe that is the issue, also checkout 6 months ago commit and check if the issue still happens there, but memory profiling is your best option here!

Comment: +1 on this. I have an app on angular 16 which runs smooth on firefox and older versions of chrome.. in the latest version the commit task slows down everything.. @NarenMurali memory is between 80MB-90MB while working with the app.. and garbage collector cycle frees the memory as it should.

Comment: @NarenMurali I checked with memory but there is no issue. For our app memory utilized is between 25MB-35MB.

Comment: Same problem with ngx-datatable